# Dividing and Deleting part of an image in inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to delete the "outside/overflow" of an image, to create a boundary with the pentagram. I have read many help articles, but feel like something strange is going on with the number of lines I have, verses two solids intersecting.
Running Inkscape 1.2 on Windows 10.
The first image is the overlay that I am trying to trim.
[image]

The second image is the result of an "intersection". I have tried a variety of combinations of the path operations, but this is the "best" one that I can get.
[image]

The 5 golden rectangles/spirals are combined into one path.
How can I simply trim the paths outside of the pentagram away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell what the exact problem is here without seeing how this has been constructed, but here are some ways you could go about creating it anyway.

**Method 1:** This will cut up everything into individual closed paths.

1. Make sure your design is converted to paths using *Path > Object to Path* - this will bake in any path effects. Ungroup everything a couple of times to make sure there are no groups. Select it all and make it a combined path.

Everything shown here is one combined path, including the pentagon

[image]

2. Draw a rectangle to surround the entire design, and set a fill so you can see what is going on, and move this rectangle to the bottom of the stack using <kbd>End</kbd>
3. Select everything, and do *Path > Division*
4. Select and delete the pieces outside the pentagon

An example

[image]

**Method 2:** Using a clipping path. I will assume the design is one group. There's no need to combine paths using this method, a group will do. Also no need to bake in any path effects. Using this method nothing is actually deleted, merely hidden by the clip.

1. Draw your pentagon over the design group, and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> *Copy* the pentagon to the clip board.
2. Select the design, and the pentagon, and do *Object > Clip > Set Clip*
3. Do *Edit > Paste in Place* to get the pentagon back

An example

[image]

**Method 3:** Use this you just want to cut up all the paths without making closed shapes.

1. Select the design and do *Path > Object to Path* to bake in any path effects, ungroup several times, and Combine the design as one path
2. Draw the pentagon on top, and copy the pentagon to the clip board
3. Select all and do *Path > Cut Path*
4. Do *Edit > Paste in Place* to bring back the pentagon
5. Select all the pieces outside the pentagon and delete

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Following your steps, I can see that I've got something funky going on in my original paths, that is causing some issue. I will redraw, and then try your methods again. Wonderful explanations.